# How to make this complex query in django python

Tags: python, django

I have the model Called  `Plan`

Plan has `state` and `city` associated with it

I have other Model called `Weather` which has data at variious times during per day for each `city` in `state`

Now i want to get all the Plan objects with extra dictionary called weather.

Steps are

1. Get all the plan objects
2. Now based on the state and city each plan will have many rows in weather table
3. i want to aggreagte all the columns .eg if i have five rows for that city and state
   and temperature values are  `20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 24` . then i want take the avg of all the temperatues i.e 22 and store in new dictionary in plan model

so that i can access `Plan.weather.temperature` and it comes `22`

I can use the for loop but that will be lot db queries . can do that on one query or what ever option is possible

EDIT:

```
class Plan(model.model):
    name = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District)
```

---

```
 class Weather(model.model):

        region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
        district = models.ForeignKey(District)
        temp_max = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Max temperature (C)')
        temp_min = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Min temperature (C)')
```

Comment: FYI: its usually a good idea to paste your models code. its much more descriptive then describing in words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your model but something like this:

`Plan.objects.filter(region__name="CA").annotate(avg_temperature=Avg("region__weather__temp_max"))`

The `avg_temperature` field will now be available on the objects returned by the query. This name is customizable based on the keyword argument provided to annotate.

Or take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Django has these kinds of queries built in. If the aggregation and annotation api can't facilitate this (seems like a strong candidate for working out of the box) then you have the option of writing a raw query:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Can i do this with dictionary like  `annotate(myweather['avg_temperature']=Avg("weather__temperature") , myweather['avg_pressure']=Avg("weather__pressure"))` and so on so that i can go further like  `myobject.weather.avg_temperature` rather than `myobject.avg_temperature`

Comment: and other question my weather object is not at all associated with Plan so we can't use `weather__temp` , we have to join the query where region and district match

Comment: For the first question, no you can't. You can simply use a funkier key like weather_avg_temperature. Just blow it up later. You're using python's keyword argument syntax here. Django does some magic to make this all work.

Comment: For the second question - just keep using Django's double underscores to follow relationships across models. E.g. region__weather__temperature. Peek at the query it's generating as well!